# Python: reverse numpy view of array with explicit indices

Tags: python, numpy

if I have a numpy array with 256 elements then

```
a[:]
```

is the same as

```
a[0:256]
```

correct?

but what's the equivalent to

```
a[::-1]
```

?

I would suspect it's

```
a[255:-1:-1]
```

but this gives me an empty array

example code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print(x[:])        #1
print(x[0:10])     #2
print(x[::-1])     #3
print(x[9:0:-1])   #4
print(x[9:-1:-1])  #5
```

will print

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]  #1
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]  #2
[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]  #3
[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]    #4
[]                     #5
```

Comment: Note: this is not unique to numpy.

Comment: `[::-1]` translates to `slice(None, None, -1)`.  There isn't an explicit index that replicates the second `None`.

Comment: I'm extracting (reverse) slices by variables. something like `subview = array[top-1:bottom-1:-1]`. Does that mean I'll have to special-case the code such as `if(bottom == 0): subview = array[top-1:None:-1] else: subview = array[top-1:bottom-1:-1]` ? would be surprised if it has to be this ugly...

Comment: Almost.  `arr[top: (None if bottom<0 else bottom): -1]` is a bit more compact.

Answer (score -1):

this:

```
x[9:0:-1]
```

means step from the 9th element *until* the 0th element by steps of -1.

To *include* the 0th element, you can try (drop the '0'):

```
x[9::-1]
```

Hope this helps.